# I'm trying to make a quiz on Python but my code keeps repeating

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to make a basic quiz in Python and when I get to a certain point when I'm testing the program my code will repeat for reasons I can't seem to work out...

My code:

`if choice == "2": #If the user enters 2 they will be taken here.

```
        print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
        username=input ("Please enter your username:")

        print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
        password=input ("Please enter your password:")

        file=open ("userinformation.txt","r")

        for line in file:

                if username and password in line:


                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print ("Thank you for logging in " + username+".")
                    time.sleep (3)

                    #file.close()


                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print ("Please choose a topic and a difficulty for your quiz.")
                    time.sleep (4)

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("a.History - Easy.") 

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("b.History - Medium.") 

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("c.History - Hard.") 

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("d.Music - Easy.")

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("e.Music - Medium.")

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("f.Music - Hard.")

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("g.Computer Science - Easy.")

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("h.Computer Science - Medium.")

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                    print("i.Computer Science - Hard.")

                    print (" ") #Makes a break between lines. 
                    topic = input("To choose a topic please enter the corrosponding letter:")

                    if topic == "a":
                        print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.
                        time.sleep(2)
                        print ("You have selected option a, History - Easy.") #Tells the user what subject they picked (Same result but with a different topic and difficulty displayed for each one

                        print (" ")
                        print ("Rules: You have an unlimited amount of time to anwser each question. You will be anwsering 2 questions and each question anwsered correctly")
                        print ("will reward you with 10 points.")
                        time.sleep(9)

                        print (" ")
                        print ("The maximum amount of points you can get is 20.")
                        time.sleep(3)

                        print (" ")
                        print ("Good luck!")
                        print (" ")
                        time.sleep(2)

                        print ("Question 1 -")
                        print ("When did World War 1 begin and end?")


                        print ("a. 1913 - 1917") #Incorrect anwser
                        print (" ")
                        print ("b. 1914 - 1919") #Incorrect anwser
                        print (" ")
                        print ("c. 1914 - 1918") #Correct anwser
                        anwserq1he = input ("Please pick an anwser:")

                        if anwserq1he == "b":
                            print(" ")
                            print("Sorry, that's the wrong anwser...")
                            time.sleep(3)
                            print(" ")
                            hisready = input ("Type ok when you are ready to proceed to the next question.")

                        elif anwserq1he == "a":
                            print(" ")
                            print("Sorry, that's the wrong anwser...")
                            time.sleep(3)
                            print(" ")
                            hisready = input ("Type ok when you are ready to proceed to the next question.")



                        elif anwserq1he == "c":
                            print(" ")
                            print ("That's the right anwser!")

                            print(" ")
                            time.sleep(2)
                            print ("Adding 10 points to your score...")

                            score = score +10

                            print(" ")
                            time.sleep(3)
                            hisready = input ("Type ok when you are ready to proceed to the next question.")



                            if hisready == "ok":
                                print(" ")
                                time.sleep(2)
                                print ("Question 2-")
                                print ("Which historical figure is commonly known as 'The lady with the lamp'?")
                                print ("a. Margaret Fuller")
                                print (" ")
                                print ("b. Florence Nightingale")
                                print (" ")
                                print ("c. Rosa Luxemburg")
                                anwserq2he = input ("Please pick an anwser:")

                                if anwserq2he == "a":
                                    print ("Sorry, that's the wrong anwser...")

                                    results = input("Please type results to get your results")

                                elif anwserq2he == "c":
                                    print ("Sorry, that's the wrong anwser...")

                                    results = input("Please type results to get your results")



                                elif anwserq2he == "b":
                                    print (" ")
                                    time.sleep(2)
                                    print ("That's the right anwser!")

                                    print(" ")
                                    time.sleep(2)
                                    print ("Adding 10 points to your score...")

                                    score = score + 10

                                    results = input("Please type results to get your results.")

                                    if results == "results":

                                        print(" ")
                                        time.sleep(3)
                                        print ("Getting your results...")

                                        if score == 20:
                                            print ("Congratulations, you scored 20 points. That's the best score you can get!")

                                        elif score == 10:
                                                   print ("Well done, you scored 10 points. Almost there!")

                                        elif score == 0:
                                                   print ("You scored 0 points. Try again and you might do better!")`
```

When I complete the quiz everything beyond `print ("Thank you for logging in " + username+".")`repeats...I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me. Thank you.

Sidenote: The #file.close is intentional.

Comment: "`for line in file:`"... I'd start from there to understand why it repeats...

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it's both minimal and verifable.

Comment: Yes it will repeat for each line, as you ask it to do. Once for each user in your userinformation.txt, assuming that one user equals one line.

Comment: What is it about "for line in file:" that's the problem though?

Comment: That runs your code for each line in the file.

Comment: Non of that stuff is in the file though?

Comment: `if username and password in line:` does not do what you probably think it does and always evaluates to true as long as any string is entered. What you want is `if username in line and password in line:`

Comment: All it did was cause the program to end when I edited the code.

Comment: What's all of those `print (" ") #Makes a break between lines.`? They clutter up the code, making it harder to read. If you want extra lines you can use the newline character `\n`. Eg `"\nPlease enter your username: "`

Comment: I didn't know how to do it and my code being cluttered doesn't really bother me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so first of all we need to improve the program layout , maybe call in some functions would be useful. Here is some tips to fix the program.

First of all use : if username.strip() and password.strip() in line: [Use the .strip() function so it will match a word.

Your program is inefficient because if you press another value as in 2 it will break the program. You want to loop it and loop it over and over again therefore use the while True statement and create a function.

## Add a function called exampleFunction() (I.E) and then on the bottom of the code ad this line but obviously indent it.

```
while True:

     exampleFunction()
```

You don't need to use a or r just do file=open("your file.txt")

For example,

```
genre=input("What is the film  you would like to search?: ")
f=open("Films.txt")
for line in f:
    if genre in line.strip():
        print(line)
```

I would personally fix this myself and post a copy of the code however this is too minor to fix therefore i'm leaving it to you.

Goodluck,

Matin

Comment: Using code from this answer and a few searches on Google I was able to solve my problem, thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help. ItsFyn